# Activity Not Responding

Tags: android

This is major problem I am getting while monkey testing my application on emulator.

> "activity home(in process
>   android.process.acore) is not
>   responding"

I don't know what is happening behind.

Has anybody any solution?

Comment: what are you doing in your activity ? explanation required.

Comment: **Without posting code here. Your Activity will never respond**

Comment: This is not the way you post a question. read the FAQ before putting them here. You are supposed to be posting as much details as possible. How else do you suppose we can know what's wrong with your code!?

Comment: thanks for giving reply friends.but my code is running well..just problem is comming while monkey testing...in activity just calling intents ....

Comment: @rohan: post your activity code. without it no one can help you.

Comment: ** Monkey aborted due to error.

Events injected: 1120

:Dropped: keys=11 pointers=6 trackballs=0 flips=0

## Network stats: elapsed time=150645ms (150645ms mobile, 0ms wifi, 0ms not connected)

** System appears to have crashed at event 1120 of 50000 using seed 0

this is monkey testing lines

Comment: @rohan: post this lines in your question so everyone notice it. use edit question option.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably doing something time-consuming (like a network connection) on the event thread. You need to move all time-consuming processing into worker threads. See the article on [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Answer (score 0):

That process don't belong to you application does it ? I think that is a system process.
Have you limited monkey to only run on your package ? Are you running emulator or target ?
Souns like monkey make your emulator or target phone "crash".

Comment: OK.
Try to set monkey to only run on your packages. to see if that helps.